# Error taking address of temporary array when passing compound literal array

Tags: array, pointer, functions

I have an Arduino sketch that passes an array into a method as a compound literal, but for some reason I keep getting the following error:

```cpp
void setup() { }
void printConcatLine(char chunks[][20]) { }

void loop() {  
  printConcatLine((char[][20]){ "{", "255", "}" });
}
```

I've also tried passing the number of the pointers/length of the array, and explicitly terminating it:

```cpp
void setup() { }
void printConcatLine(char *chunks[]) { }

void loop() {  
  printConcatLine((char*[]){ "{", "255", "}", NULL });
}
```

...and

```cpp
void setup() { }
void printConcatLine(char chunks[][20]) { }

void loop() {  
  printConcatLine((char[][20]){ "{", "255", "}", "" });
}
```

But they both produce the same error.

What is the correct method of passing the compound literal array as a method parameter?

Comment: You can't. You have to assign it to something then pass that variable.

Comment: Either that or rewrite your function to use variadic arguments.

Comment: Is this limitation specific to Arduino? From what I understand you can do this in C.

Comment: I am not sure, but I suspect it's a consequence of the AVR being a Modified Harvard Architecture CPU.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941846/c-error-taking-address-of-temporary-array

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with that function anyway?

Comment: I needed a method to print any number of strings/variables together in a single line, to get past the limitation of having to send one at a time to Serial.print. I wanted to achieve the same functionality of something similar to: Serial.println( "{" + var1 " - " + var2 + "}" );

Comment: Actually Arduino uses C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with the Arduino. I am not quite sure why, but I think it may be because it's a Modified Harvard architecture machine.

You can better achieve what you want with *[variadic](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html) arguments*, however:

```
void printConcatLine(int num, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    const char *s;

    va_start(ap, num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        s = va_arg(ap, const char *);
        Serial.print(s);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    printConcatLine(3, "{", "255", "}");
}

void loop() {

}
```

The first argument is the number of arguments that follow, and all the rest are string constants.